# Django update_or_create and if value equal then pass

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use update_or_create this function a while time, but I want to set a judgment to detect the value is equal what I update then pass if not, then update or create (I don't want to waste my session to do the meaningless update, like value 123 update to 123)

```
kwargs['time'] = "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
kwargs['id'] = 1
update_kwargs['value'] = 123
instance, created = MyModel.objects.update_or_create(**kwargs, defaults=update_kwargs)
```

Comment: try `MyModel.objects.exclude(value=123).update_or_create(…)`

Comment: Of course Django ORM is supposed to be "lazy".  How do you know your session is executing meaningless updates?  Does your model have something like `update_datetime` field? Maybe you could verify if meaningless updates are happening or not.

Comment: You can override the update_or_create method in MyModel class and check instance.value there